# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS video problems

Tags: 14.04, boot, display

I am looking to switch my system over from Ubuntu 15.10 to 14.04 LTS. However, i encounter problems when booting from the thumb drive. During boot up, the Ubuntu start splash is displayed normally. Then my monitor will tell me that it is readjusting to the screen, then the splash is off to the left about 1-2 inch.

Then my monitor tells me that the "input is out of range." The video card i have in my system is  a nvidia card and it is the geforce GTX 970.

**note** : this is from the live CD in the thumb drive. Not the 14.04 is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media you have created.
Highlight **Try Ubuntu without installing** and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the parameter `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu Live desktop environment.